# Merging data sets from two tables with origin reference

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, sorting

In a Google Sheet, I have multiple tables containing a list of dates.
I want to create a single (sorted) list containing all the dates and the table they came from.

```
Table foo:
1.1.19
3.1.19

Table bar:
2.1.19
4.1.19

Result:
1.1.19 foo
2.1.19 bar
3.1.19 foo
4.1.19 bar
```

Is this somehow possible with regular formulas or do I need to switch to custom functions here?

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(SPLIT({
 QUERY(IF(LEN(A2:A), A2:A&"♦foo", ), "where Col1 !=''", 0); 
 QUERY(IF(LEN(C6:C), C6:C&"♦bar", ), "where Col1 !=''", 0)}, "♦"), 1, 1))
```

[image: 0]